# Converting Date to CurrentCompany timeZone in Dynamics ax x++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, timezone-offset

I have a scenario where i need to convert a Datefield(joindate) to currentcompany timezone date. And then i need to compare this with anotherdate(startdate). If the difference is more than 365 days i need to give an warning. Can someone help me in this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a timezone to an `utcdatetime` via [DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/datetimeutil.applytimezoneoffset.aspx)
The company timezone can be retrieved by calling [DateTimeUtil::getCompanyTimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/datetimeutil.getcompanytimezone.aspx)

Afterwards calculate the difference by calling [DateTimeUtil::getDifference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/datetimeutil.getdifference.aspx), which returns the difference in seconds so you have to compare that with the seconds per year.
To avoid inserting a 'magic' number, use the constants in the macro library `TimeConstants`.

Answer (score 1):

If Datefield(joindate) is of type `date` and not `utcDateTime` then [`DateTimeUtil::newDateTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/datetimeutil.newdatetime.aspx) should be used to convert it to `utcDateTime`:

> utcDateTime joinDateTime = DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(joindate, 0,
>   DateTimeUtil::getCompanyTimeZone());

[`DateTimeUtil::getDifference()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/datetimeutil.getdifference.aspx) can be used to get the number of seconds between the `utcDateTime` values.

If both Datefield(joindate) and anotherdate(startdate) are of type `date` and not `utcDateType` then no conversion is required at all, and you can check whether the difference is more than 365 as follows:

> if (joindate - startdate > 365) {}

If the above assumptions are wrong, see DAXaholic's answer.